# CLI application using Google APIs

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-photos-api

I want to create an application that will download all my photos in Google Photos. I thought it should be easy with the API available.

This should be an CLI application that will run periodically from cron.
But when I looked at the Google Photos API, they use OAuth2.
The sample shows the usage of FixedCredentials:

```
PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
     PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
    .setCredentialsProvider(
        FixedCredentialsProvider.create(/* Add credentials here. */)) 
    .build();
```

The problem is the part where the `/* Add credentials here. */` is. How can I provide my user credentials there? There are numerous classes that implement `Credentials` but none of them look like ones that would allow me to automate retrieval in a CLI application.

The only thing I get from Google is the client_id and client_token for my app, but how to turn that into an access/refresh token so I can use it without my interaction?

I really hope I don't need to launch a web browser to download my photos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention explains how you can easily do this

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks, that was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Photos Library API only accepts OAuth ***User Credentials***. This means that users are required to complete the Google OAuth Flow, which means browser based Authorization.

> Note: The Library API does not support service accounts. Your
>   application must use the other OAuth 2.0 flows available such as OAuth
>   2.0 for web server applications or OAuth 2.0 for mobile and desktop apps.
>
> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other
>   authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google
>   Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

This links details these requirements:

[Authentication and authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authentication-authorization)